# « Pléonasmique » et pléonastique : pourquoi ?

Tags: adjectifs, orthographe, origine-ou-raison, suffixes

On avait anciennement l'adjectif *pléonasmique* attesté en 1546 (DHLF), puis par substitution de suffixe (-atique à -asme) on est passé à [*pléonastique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pl%C3%A9onastique) (attesté en 1842 ; en anglais en 1778) (TLFi) ; les deux graphies de l'adjectif partagent la finale en [-ique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ique).

---

Peut-on expliquer pourquoi et généralement dans quel contexte on a effectué cette substitution au 19<sup>e</sup> ?

- Quel était le but recherché ou quelle raison justifie d'« éloigner » l'adjectif de la morphologie du nom, en quoi c'est une substitution du suffixe *-atique* à *-asme* et non simplement la substitution (arbitraire) d'une lettre (*t* pour *m*), y a-t-il d'autres mots qui ont subi le même sort durant cette période, a-t-on déjà songé à revenir à l'ancienne graphie de l'adjectif (par exemple lors de *rectifications* subséquentes) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voyons voir... (Non ce ne l'est pas... :-) )

D'abord, l'existence de *pléonasmique* en 1546 a dû être très discrète. :
Je ne le retrouve pas plus dans le DMF que dans le Godefroy et encore moins dans Académie IV et suivantes. Mais ce sont là mes seule références ici maintenant.

Mais dans le fond, je ne trouve pas cela bien étonnant étant donnée sa curieuse malformation.

Dans les emprunts au latin et au grec via le latin, le bon sens, la facilité commandent (comme je l'ai déjà expliqué sur un autre propos) qu'on emprunte la forme du mot suivant sa classe. v.g. un substantif pour un substantif, un adjectif pour un adjectif plutôt que de ne reprendre que le substantif pour ensuite adjectiver sa forme française.

Ici en l'occurence si pléonasme est emprunté au grec (via le latin) *pleonas**M**os* l'adjectif grec est bien *pleonas**T**icos*.

Ce pléonas**T**ique, aurait donc, de toute logique lexicale, dû être la première et seule orthographe connue.

Pour une raison que j'ignore mais qui pourrait justement être... l'ignorance, on a initialement adjectivé le substantif français. Quand certains savants (car le mot appartient au langage savant) ont éprouvé le besoin d'en user, ils sont revenus au simple bon sens lexical.

Il ne s'agit donc pas là d'une mutation arbitraire, il s'agit juste d'un retour aux sources, d'un retour au bon sens.

D'autres mots de même genre ( n'ayant donc pas subi quelque *sort* que ce soit ), on peut penser à *fantas**M**e* repris en // avec *fantas**T**ique* pour la raison évoquée ci-dessus. Le substantif français sera par suite adjectivé (fantasmatique) et vivra sa vie en toute indépendance de l'adjectif initial.

<sub>jlliagre évoque en commentaires le couple authentique et juste (*orgasme* / *orgastique*) auquel on aura tout fait subir...

Il est au demeurant très curieux celui-là puisque son antonyme reste curieusement *anorgasmique*.

Ha! on me soufle que c'est justement parce qu'ils ne sont pas antonymes. ???

Quelques recherches expérimentales s'imposent...</sub>

<sub>Dans un autre commentaire, jlliagre propose une liste dont j'extrais ici en particulier *autisme* (substantif) et son adjectif *autistique* simplifié depuis en *autiste*. Le substantif *autiste* existe certes lui aussi mais sans être repris directement du substantif latin puisqu'il s'agit là, au contraire de l'adjectif substantivé.</sub>

---

Pour répondre à un commentaire de L'OP :

A/ Le FEW : Oui absolument, pléonasMique... dans l'entrée de PLÉONASME... avec... un ***Ablt.*** précédent c'est bien à dire **Ableitung** : dérivé. Oui! PléonasMique est bien, comme affirmé plus haut, un dérivé du substantif pléonasme.

B/ Rabelais. C'est dans le Tiers livre. Au chapitre 38. *"Comment par Pantagruel et Panurge est Triboulet blasonné.* (Cela dit en V.F. ce qu'avec Jarry, amoureux de Rabelais, je réprouve fermement) et on y va gaiment avec le *pléonasmique* dans une litanie d'adjectifs parmi lesquels on observera aussi... patriarc**H**al, monac**H**al, métaphysi**CAL**, d'algorisme, d'algébrale... quelques *"néologismes-en-tant-que-tels"* effectivement issus de substantifs en dépit de toute règle lexicale quand ce n'est pas, vous l'aurez noté avec *d'algébrale* de vrais adjectifs présentifiés substantivement... (fabuleux, simplément génial!), juste plantés-là pour leur forme leur sonorité... leur... **incongruence**, RIEN QUE pour le **JEU** (en témoigne la présentation), bref... du Rabelais quoi!, en plein dans un exercice qui n'appartient qu'à lui.

Certainement, en tout cas, pas de quoi forger un mot à réutiliser ailleurs par le monde des sachants. (Cela étant réaffirmé que j'adore ce Rabelais que je tiens (mais c'est aujourd'hui un lieu commun <sup>1</sup>) pour rien moins que fondateur des lettres françaises.)
i.e. : Des lettres, pas des mots...

<sub>1: NDaCOSwt cette absolue platitude ajoutée en raison d'un reproche à moi adressé par quelque *assermenté* de me livrer, dans le cadre de mes réponses ici, à des égarements personnels. QHAAA.</sub>

Comment: Orgasme, orgastique...

Comment: @jlliage : Ha oui! Merci pour celui-là. D'autant qu'il est très curieux relativement à la formation de ce que je croyais son antonyme et que je ne suis pas parvenu à retracer. Réponse augmentée en conséquence.

Comment: En voilà d'autres : autisme - autistique, hellénisme - hellénistique, journalisme - journalistique, paroxysme - paroxystique, sarcasme - sarcastique, sophisme - sophistique, spasme - spastique, stylisme - stylistique, syllogisme - syllogistique, tourisme - touristique...

Comment: Houlàa! Toussa ? Merci encore! Je ne reprend qu'*autisme* dans ma réponse pour un cas particulier qu'il représente.

Comment: Merci ! Voir au [FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/197354), je pense qu'on dit Rabelais et ds le Cotgrave(1611) mais une brève recherche ne m'a pas permis de le retrouver. N'hésitez pas à lier l'autre propos auquel vous faites référence. Les savants ne _sçavent_ pas tout. Y a-t-il un Vaugelas de cette époque qui commente ? Savez-vous ce qui se passe historiquement au 19e avec la langue, est-ce le siècle le plus latinisant ? Le fait que ça appartienne au lexique savant, ça donne un parcours différent, parallèle, des autres mots en français ; comment résumer ?

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme : J'adresse vos deux premiers points en fin de ma réponse. Pour ce qui est d'un Vaugelas de cette époque, vous voulez dire un grammairien du XVIè ? Auquel cas, je pense que le plus *en vue / influent* est sans doute Robert Estienne. Le plus prolixe et le premier étant... force est de l'admettre... un Anglais! Eh oui! Palsgrave (Lesclarcissement de la langue francoyse (1530)) après il reste deux ou trois autres plus obscurs. Quant à ce qui se passe au XIX°... cela pourrait faire l'objet d'une question à part. Je crois.

Comment: Je trouve des plus agréable cette réponse qui va et vient au gré de la réflexion, mais il me reste une petite interrogation. Je veux bien qu'à une époque on soit allé et venu repiger au grec et au latin, afin de mimiquer leur déclinaisons et tout et tout. Mais il semble qu'aujourd'hui, une autre dynamique ait été mise en place: on assiste à la fusion de racines de plusieurs langues en un seul mot (grec et latin pour automobile, hawaiien et grec via l'anglais pour Wikipédia, etc.) et l'on recommende que les ajustements en genre et en nombre soient francisés (inuit/inuits, pas inuk/inuit).

Comment: Quand et comment serait survenue la transition? Vous sentiriez-vous le courage d'éclairer un peu cette transition, puisque vous semblez prendre parti pour la manière classique de créer les mots, ou devrais-je en faire une nouvelle question?

Comment: @Montéedelait : - Merci pour le compliment auquel je suis d'autant plus sensible que je vous sais critique. - *Me sentirais-je le courage* ? Il y a quarante ans... j'aurais pris cela pour une provo et vous aurait pondu 50 pages en moins de temps qu'il ne m'en faut maintenant pour rédiger ce commentaire. Ha! Bug! Comment aurais-je pu faire 50 pages sur une question qui... ne se serait pas posée... hmmm! - *Je semble prendre partie ?* hic&nunc, oui nécessairement! Chaque mot que j'écris, que vous écrivez, est un parti pris à lui tout seul. Mais un parti pris... hic&nunc.

Comment: @Montéedelait : D'ailleurs, à propos de vos *inuits*, j'en ai un autre de parti-pris. Je l'ai déjà exposé ici : http://chasseautresor-ng.0707a.net/forum/index.php?topic=15.0 - Pour en revenir à l'éclairage que vous demandez, FSE ne me semble pas présenter assez de garanties relativement à l'intégrité de ma réponse. La tenant, sur ce sujet absolument fondamentale, on se retrouvera donc ailleurs pour en discuter.